# Download file size - JavaME

Tags: java, java-me

I am trying to download a file from http server using httpconnection. Can I get the size of the file before I download. If so, how do i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So HTTP usually uses GET requests or POST requests.  But there's also HEAD requests, which just returns the header without the actual file.  The header tells you the length of the contents (i.e. the file size), so you can try doing a HEAD request first, parsing it to determine the file size, and take the appropriate action from there.

Answer (score 1):

The `inputStream.available()` is what you think you want, but that's not reliable. Instead you should always resort to reading a fixed size of bytes (usually, 4k) from the stream.

Also, as @muddybruin mentioned, the Content-Length header returns the size of the stream if the response is **not chunked.**